# what is the best way to find the topper by subject?

Tags: java, collections

I have a string array of student info:

```
StudentNumber Integer, Subject String, mmarks integer
```

What would be the best way to use the java & collection to find out the topper in each subject.

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("1 | Computers | 48");
strings.add("2 | Data Structures | 89");
strings.add("33 | English | 35");
strings.add("24 | Maths | 70");
strings.add("15 | Computers | 58");
strings.add("6 | Data Structures | 55");
strings.add("7 | English | 40");
strings.add("18 | Maths | 73");

for (String str : strings) {
    String [] strArray = str.split("\\|");
    // in completed code 
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        sam.put(strArray[0], strArray[2]);
        s.add(strArray[1]);
    }
}
```

**Expected output**

> 15 Computers
>       2 Data structures
>       7 English
>       18 Maths

Comment: Questions. What is a topper? Your code can't compile, what is `sam` and what is `s`?

Comment: Oh wait.  I think I know what you want.  Do you have to start with an `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: I know, it is in completed one, I was trying to split string by | and add to array , put all Subjects in Map as key and Student number and marks as a value in form of object.

Comment: Yes, I have to start with ArrayList<String>.

Comment: What do you mean by topper? Anyone?

Comment: @user3437460 Either me ..... or the student with the highest mark  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Result` class to store the information:

```
class Result {
    private int studentNumber;
    private String subject;
    private int mark;

    // constructor, getters and setters go here ...
}
```

Now convert your `List<String>` to a `List<Result>`:

```
List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : strings){
    String[] sa = s.split(" \\| ");
    results.add(new Result(Integer.parseInt(sa[0]), sa[1], Integer.parseInt(sa[2])));
}
```

Create a stream from the `results` list, group by subject, and find the student with the highest mark:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = results.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Result::getSubject, 
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Result::getMark)), r -> r.get().getStudentNumber())));
```

Print the result:

```
map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(v + " " + k));

15 Computers
18 Maths
7 English
2 Data Structures
```

Comment: How to do the same without using java 8 ?